# Where is the best place to ask questions regarding iOS development terms of use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know that Apple likes to lock down all information associated with Mac/iOS development, but I have a somewhat general question that I'd like to ask regarding the publication of a specific type of application.  Is such a question appropriate on StackOverflow, or some where else within the network?

*Update*

For reference, here is the jist of my question.

--

I'd like to build a SolidCoin (similar to [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/)) thin-client for the iOS, but it won't need to manage the block-chain.  Is this allowed by the Apple Developer TOS?

Comment: Depending on the question, it may be appropriate on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but do check the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) first. You have not given enough information to determine whether such a question would fit _anywhere_ on the network.

Comment: That sounds like the type of question that you should ask Apple.

Comment: Apple can be unreliable (go figure) and I'd rather not take the time to write an application, publish it and then have it pulled for breaking the TOS.  If there is a developer out there that knows what they are talking about and has experience in this area, I'd like to get their advice.

Comment: If Apple is as "unreliable" as you say, you could get a well-intentioned answer from another developer and comply with its recommendations, and then Apple could *still* pull your application for breaking the TOS. Again, this is something that you should ask Apple. They're quite willing to help developers who *wish* to follow their guidelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of question should be directed at Apple (or Google if developing for Android, or Microsoft if developing for Windows Phone 7).

Any answer you get from someone on Stack Exchange is likely to be wrong.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I just assumed that someone has probably looked into this type of thing and I've found Apple to some times be unreliable.  I'd rather get a "cautious" answer from another, more experienced developer.

Comment: Specifically, http://devforums.apple.com (requires iOS Dev Program membership)